# How to download a file attached to a list Item (Content Type is "Item")

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list-item

#### Scenario:

1. Create List Item using form.
2. Attache a file to said form. (Example temp.xls)
3. Right-Click save-as

#### Expected Result:

A copy of the original file (temp.xls) is save to the file system.

#### Actual Result:

A copy of WopiFrame.aspx is saved to the file system.

#### Note:

If you left-click the link it opens in the browser.
If you try to save that to the file system, it warns you that the file downloaded will not contain content that is not supported by the web editor.

#### Update #1:

- Using the Office 365 SharePoint Client.

Comment: For what SharePoint version is it? Because on 2013, Right-Clicking the link and press "Save target as..." works fine.

Comment: Version is Office 365. Updating question.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a very pleasant way to do this, but it works:

1. Copy the link URL:

   - https://afs365.sharepoint.com/sites/ApplicationName/**Release/_layouts/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc=/sites/ApplicationName/**Release/Lists/Some%20Folder/Attachments/263/temp.xlsm**&action=default**
2. Cut out the WopiFrame information highligted in bold:

   - https://afs365.sharepoint.com/sites/ApplicationName/Release/Lists/Some%20Folder/Attachments/263/temp.xlsm
3. Paste the updated link into your browsers address bar and hit enter.